# Hiding a DIV on page load

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to hide a DIV element which contains bunch of other child elements on page load but it doesnt seem to be working fine. 
 This page is a popup, opened using window.open where I attach some of my own custom information. 
This DIV is question comes by default from the server and I have no control over it, only possible way is through javascript. 
What I have so far:

```
require(["dojo/ready", "dojo/query"], function(ready, query) {
        ready(function(){
           console.log("This statement is being logged fine.....");
           hideMyForm();                 
        });
  });


function hideMyForm()
{
 var elem = document.getElementById('divInQuestion');
 elem.display = 'none';
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `elem.style.display = 'none';`

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
elem.style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you go for jQuery? 
Include jQuery and then use 
   $('#divInQuestion').hide();